# What do backslashes in WP generated robots.txt rules mean?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I am trying to implement a library to handle robots.txt and I am a bit confused about the meaning of some rules that I believe are generated by WordPress:

```
Disallow: /?s=*
Disallow: /*/?s=*\
Disallow: /\\?s=*
```

I have seen these rules on multiple WP sites.

I understand the first line, forbid entries with `s` parameter. But what do the other lines forbid? What is the meaning of the backslash characters in these lines?

Could someone give me an example or two for these 2 rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes in disallow rules are literals.  Neither the [original robots.txt specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9309/), nor [Google's extended interpretation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values) treat `/` in any way specially.

My guess is that some WP plugin is adding those rules erroneously. [Backslashes are not safe URL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695467) so they shouldn't appear as literals in URLs.

Comment: Thought so, but was not sure. Thank you!